# People in a train realise their planet is attacked by powerful and vicious aliens

Tags: story-identification, aliens, space

This short fiction (short novella ? long novelette ?) is clearly SF : it happens on a sparsely settled planet far from the main human settled worlds, during a fierce attack by cruel aliens.

I read it maybe "only" 10-15 years ago, probably in a collection. I have no idea how long before that it had been first published.

Various people are travelling by train for professional reasons, going towards ever less densely settled parts.
Suddenly, the planet is attacked by aliens which rapidly overpower all its defenses.

But the story is mostly a sociological/psychological study about the reactions of the people in the train and the small places where they stop, reacting to radio broadcasts bringing ever worse news until the end of all broadcasts becomes the worst possible piece of news.

Comment: hear or here? i think latter is what u intended?

Comment: Are the aliens a different species? Or are they humans from another planet?

Comment: @releseabe Neither. I originally wrote "hear" then decided that "realise" was better and forgot to erase the first choice... Sorry...

Comment: @PM2Ring I have the feeling it was a different species, but I am not sure . One never sees them, only their flying war machines (which IIRC were given "human" names but then aerodynamics are species-independent). But maybe from a different human political entity. The planet belonged to one, though rather far from its center.

Comment: If I were writing this I'd call it _The End of the Line_. However a quick IFSDB search shows dozens of stories with minor variants of that title.

Comment: @JohnRennie   This title does not specially ring a bell, but I cannot exclude a similar one, it was long ago !

Comment: Ok. If they *were* humans from a different political entity it *might* be one of H. Beam Piper's Terro Human Future History stories. I last read those stories a decade or so ago, and my memory is a little fuzzy. ;) I just checked a couple of suspects on Project Gutenberg, but they didn't match.